# Django. FormView: request в __init__()

Tags: python, django

Как в __ init__() получить доступ к request или session

```
class RegistrationView(FormView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # super(RegistrationView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.step = self.request.session.get('step', '')
```

На выходе

```
AttributeError at /accounts/registration/
'RegistrationView' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Comment: Никак, потому что во время работы `__init__` Django не передаёт `request` в FormView никаким образом. Используйте def get/post/put вместо этого (и про super не забывайте)

Comment: Проблема просто в том, что я переопределяю потом и get_form_class, и get_context_data, и get_template_names. И везде нужен "step". Получается, что в каждом методе приходится его заново получать. Как-то не DRY получается. Но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы указали одну из причин, почему я ненавижу class-based views и использую старые добрые вьюхи-функции вместо вот этого вот нагромождения классов и методов. :)

Comment: Хотя, возможно, у вас просто где-то косяк в архитектуре сайта, но я не имею достаточно информации, чтобы корректно судить об этом

Comment: На самом деле это попытка переписать view-функцию в CBV. Так как в функции получилось большая цепочка из if-elif, плюс вложенные if, словом читаемость стала ужасной. А вообще цель была сделать пошаговую регистрацию но с одни url. И в итоге когда функция превысила 150 строк, стало как-то сложно ориентироваться, а вот класс как-то читается проще, но очень сильно смущает момент с отсутствием request'а в init'е.

Comment: Ну, CBV не является волшебным средством от нечитаемого кода. View-функции вполне можно делать лаконичными и понятными, если уметь :)

Comment: @Ins, зачем в каждом методе? Получите его в том методе, который выполняется первым, а затем используйте